# standard VCS ignore list

Tags: subversion, git, version-control

What all do you think is the best standard list of ignored files for VCS? For example here's my .gitignore_global file.

```
# Compiled Sources #
###################
*.pyc
*.pyo
*.exe
*.so
*.o
*.a
*.la
*.dex
*.class
*.elf
*.ko


# Build Enviornment #
#####################
CMakeCache.txt
CMakeFiles


# Packages #
############
*.bz2
*.iso
*.dmg
*.7z
*.tar
*.gz
*.zip
*.apk
*.ap_



# Logs and Databases #
######################
*.log
*.sql
*.sqlite


# OS and Application #
######################
.DS_Store
enthumbs.db
*~
*.sw?
Thumbs.db


# IDE Crap #
############

# Eclipse
.classpath
.project
.metadeta
.pydevproject
.cproject


# KDevelop
*.kdev4


cscope.*
ncscope.*

# Other VCS #
#############
.svn
.hg

!.gitignore

*.old
*.orig
\#*#
```

Any comments? Things I'm missing? Things that should be there? (I'm sure I'm missing windows ones. Feel free to add them, but I don't dev on windows so I'm going to stay out =] )

I'm trying to keep this as project/language/IDE agnostic as possible. Ie I know the `bin` and `gen` folders in android projects should be ignored, but that should go in the `.gitignore` file in the project imo.

Comment: You aren't going to come up with anything like a “standard” list. Every project is different. My main project at work has a few `.exe` and `.tgz` checked in (hint: we didn't build them), and some `bin` directories. And note that an ignore list not stored within the project is potentially annoying and harmful: you may be forgetting patterns that are needed in the project (annoying other people) and you may be missing some project files (so not getting some of your files committed).

Comment: That's a good point. Maybe instead, is there a way to make "git init" copy a .gitignore template from somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Github project that has `.gitignore` files for many different languages and environments.

https://github.com/github/gitignore